# Change content before preview in TinyMCE 4

Tags: tinymce, editor

In TinyMCE 4, I want to change displayed contents before they are showed on preview popup windows. This change must not affect current contents in editor. Can we do that?

If it can't, I want to catch close event of preview windows. How to do that?

Answer (score 5):

TinyMCE allows us to register callbacks via the property [init_instance_callback](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/integration-and-setup/#init_instance_callback)

By using the [BeforeExecCommand event](http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:event.tinymce.Editor.BeforeExecCommand), oddly not in current documentation, you can make changes prior to a command being executed. We can similarly use the [ExecCommand event](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/events/#execcommand) to make changes after the command is executed. The Preview Plugin triggers the `mcePreview` command. You can view the [Editor command Identifiers here](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/editor-command-identifiers/).

Putting that together you can add the following when initializing your TinyMCE. This will show "changed content" in the preview without making visible changes to the content within TinyMCE.

```
var preProssesInnerHtml; 
tinymce.init({
    //other things...
    init_instance_callback: function (editor) {
        editor.on('BeforeExecCommand', function (e) {
            if (e.command == "mcePreview") {
                //store content prior to changing.
                preProssesInnerHtml = editor.getContent();
                editor.setContent("changed content");
            }
        });
        editor.on("ExecCommand", function (e) {
            if (e.command == "mcePreview") {
                //Restore initial content.
                editor.setContent(preProssesInnerHtml);
            }
        });
    }
}
```